# An adverb challenge

Tags: adverbs

I was set the challenge to provide one particular adverb that can be used as verb modifier, adjective modifier and adverb modifier, and an example of its use in each of the cases. In addition the answer should avoid the use of adjectival participles.

Can you help?

Comment: Did somebody really give you this challenge? It's really difficult. You may have to think really hard to get an answer, especially if using intensifiers isn't allowed.

Comment: @peter Shor. Yes. I had a discussion with an English colleague about grammar. It all started when I told him about  a comment I made to a student about his coursewok: "stop writing `spelt wrong' because it's real bad. :)" He did not believe that "really", in "really bad", was an adverb. So I explained my understanding of adverbs and this led to the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

There is the adverb *softly* -

> **Verb**
>
> Speak softly, and carry a big stick.
>
> **Adjective**
>
> The puppy's fur was *softly* soft.
>
> **Adverb**
>
> Here there and everywhere *softly*.

Comment: I suspect there may be many... maybe you can explain what's so special about softly?  why not "roughly","lately","soon"?

Comment: @d'alar'cop I didn't say softly was unique or special. I just answered the question. Feel free to make an answer with an adverb of your own choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found another example:

**Verb**

He totally trusts you.

**Adjective**

He remained totally still.

**Adverb**

We proceeded totally differently.